# Reading a Text File Stored Online

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am trying to read a text file which is stored online in my Android Studio application.
I have tried some code which seems to crash my app as soon as the app opens. Here is the code which I have tried:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    mWebView.clearCache(true);

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://urlhere.co.uk/files/testFile.txt");

        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line;
        String link = null;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            link = line;
        }
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + link);
        br.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print("test test");
    }

}
```

Just as a bit of explanation. The text file contains a URL which is going to be loaded into the webview. This is the best way I think to do it for the thing I am trying to do.

**UPDATE**
I used logcat and got some errors which I believe are caused by this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why my app is crashing straight away?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. You can find this exception in the logcat.

Comment: @greenapps Hi thanks for the response. I don't use logcat. I build the APK because it takes seconds and then install it onto a mobile device. Can I find this exception anywhere else?

Comment: `I don't use logcat.` ???  It is there! You dont have to do anything for that! You just should look in it. And further: what is it that you try to say? Of course you build an apk and install it on a device and let it run. What else?

Comment: If that is the actual URL http://urlhere.co.uk/files/testFile.txt I get redirected to localhost. can you hit the URL and get the file with a browser? Try using a plugin like https://www.sap.com/developer/how-tos/2017/07/api-tools-postman-install.html

Comment: @Pomagranite No that is not the actual url, i just used it as a placeholder

Comment: @greenapps Please look at the update in the question

Comment: You're trying to cast the connection to HttpsURLConnection but your URL is HTTP, not HTTPS.

Comment: `Thanks in advance` O i hate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the network in a background thread. An `AsyncTask` is good for both doing this and accessing the result on the UI thread afterwards. Something like this:

```
try {
    final URL url = new URL("http://urlhere.co.uk/files/testFile.txt");
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br;
                try {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    String line;
                    if ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        return line;
                    }
                } finally {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String link) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + link);            
        }
    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(Also, use `URLConnection` (or `HttpURLConnection`) with `http`. The cast to `HttpsURLConnection` works with `https` -- but it looks like you discovered that already.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replies. I can't believe it was such a simple fix. By changing to a http not https object it got rid of the first error displayed in update 1.

However this caused a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException error which I believe is because I am not using Async. I will leave this question posted for anyone in the future who also occurs this problem.

Again, thanks to all the replies